# line plot focus on specific range of y-axis in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a table A like

```
Age     Income
16      90000
18    2000000
19      60000
20      60000
21      50000
22      60000
23      55000
24      50000
26      63333
27      50000
28    1030000
29      20000
31      45000
33      70000
34      50000
35      43333
36      20000
37      20000
38      80000
39      50000
40      80000
41      60000
42      40000
43      35000
44      60000
45      55000
46      65000
47      50000
48    2000000
49    2000000
```

the tableA is the result of

```
tableA.groupby(['Age'])['Rounded_Incomes'].mean().astype(int).plot(kind='line')
```

As some incomes is very large like 2000000 or 1030000.. so the result like:

[image]

How to plot the line char focus on the small figures like from 18000 ~ 80000, but still have the large figure (1030000/2000000) in the graph?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tableA.groupby(['Age'])['Rounded_Incomes'].mean().astype(int).plot(kind='line')
plt.ylim(18000, 80000)
```

Also, putting your y-axis on a log scale might help.

```py
tableA.groupby(['Age'])['Rounded_Incomes'].mean().astype(int).plot(kind='line', logy=True)
```

Comment: thanks @Tim Do you know how to plot range 18000 ~ 80000 and range 100000 ~ 2000000 in the same graph?

Comment: No prob.   



`# Say that df = tableA.groupby(['Age'])['Rounded_Incomes'].mean().astype(int).plot(kind='line')

x = list(df.index)
y = list(df['Income'])


# Initialize figure and axis1
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))

# Create the second axis
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

# Plot on the first axis
ax1.plot(x, y, 'r-')

# Plot on the second
ax2.plot(x, y, 'b-')`

Comment: `# First axes configuration
ax1.set_xlabel('Age', fontsize = 16)
ax1.set_ylabel('Income (18k to 80k)', color='g', fontsize = 16)
ax1.set_ylim(18000, 80000)

# Second axes configuration
ax2.set_xlabel('Age')
ax2.set_ylabel('Income (100k to 2M)', color='b', fontsize = 16)
ax2.set_ylim(100000, 2000000)


plt.show()`